# Override class method, keep original parameters and type annotation?

Tags: typescript

I am successfully overriding a class method `Parser.parseString()` with the code below.

Does TypeScript (4.7) offer a way to make this code shorter by telling the new method to just take in the original parameter set, without having to redeclare them?

Something like this (pseudo-code) for example?

```js
class MyParser extends Parser {
  parseString(*): * {
    return super.parseString(*).then((feed) => {
      feed.entries = feed.items;
      delete feed["items"];
      return feed;
    });
  }
}
```

Here is the working code

```
import Parser from "rss-parser";

const xml = `
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
  <title>My Example Feed</title>
  <link>https://example.com</link>
  <description>My Example Feed</description>
  <item>
    <guid isPermaLink="false">com.example.feed1.item1</guid>
    <title>My Example Item</title>
    <description>An item in my sample feed</description>
  </item>
</channel>
</rss> 
`;

class MyParser extends Parser {
  parseString(
    xml: string,
    callback?:
      | ((err: Error, feed: Parser.Output<{ [key: string]: any }>) => void)
      | undefined
  ): Promise<{ [key: string]: any } & Parser.Output<{ [key: string]: any }>> {
    return super.parseString(xml, callback).then((feed) => {
      feed.entries = feed.items;
      return feed;
    });
  }
}

(async () => {
  const myParser: MyParser = new MyParser();
  const feed = await myParser.parseString(xml);
  console.log("feed.items: " + feed.items);
  console.log("feed.entries: " + feed.entries);
})();
```

Or find it on codesandbox.io:

https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-qjnge4?file=/index.ts

Comment: Please make this a [mre] by removing the dependency of the example code on rss-parser.  Also apparently `feed.items` is not optional so `delete feed["items"]` is in error, which you're not really asking about; could you fix that?

Comment: There is no shorthand to inherit parameter and return types from parent methods; there was some work to do this automatically, see [ms/TS#23911](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23911), but it hasn't gone anywhere yet.  You can do this manually with `...args: Parameters<...>` like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Nlevlm) shows, but that's not often any more convenient then typing out the things manually to begin with.  Does this fully address your question?  If so I can write up an answer explaining it; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Sounds like a recipe for unmaintainable code. The function's arguments and return types are, well, sort of important parts of what the function does.

Comment: Hi, yeah that answers it pretty good, thanks. What about the Return type? Is there a shorthand for that aswell? Regarding the minimal working example, the page you linked does not talk about dependencies. And removing the dependency maybe removes complexity that changes the answer. So I will leave it like it is. The sandbox-link I added can be used if you do not want to download packages on your local machine, but still check out the example.

Comment: If you're not asking a question *about* rss-parser then it's unlikely that you need to import it to demonstrate what you're talking about.  And you can also grab `ReturnType<>` but I don't think I'd call it a *short*hand.  Look at [this playground link](//tsplay.dev/mqk5qw) and tell me if it works for you, including removing the third-party dependencies.  It might not say "third party dependencies" in the docs for [mre], but the point is to be *minimal* and *complete*, and it's hard to be either of those when the code is not self-contained.  Anyway if this works I'll write it up. Let me know.

Comment: Maybe you could use class field instead of a method? Like `parseString: Parser['parseString'] = (...args) => { ... }`. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBABQIZQM4FMpwGZQiOAIjVQFowUMpCBuOAKHoGMAbJVVOAWQE9k1McdAA8Y6AHYATTvypwA3vTjK4FAQGUYUYOIDmALkSVMAbQDkajJu16zAXTgBeOAAoAdB5S7UASicA+BSUVEKh0GABXKHE4VAiwTDdLdGsdXXdPKG8fNxgACwkXF2x0dEk-R0DFEJqVErK3CS1gdE5nesk3YDEQVBpg2tDwqJiO-sG4AF8fcZVJ+kmgA)